# Splitting a csv files into multiple file with overlapping rows using python

Tags: python, csv, split

I'm currently trying to split my csv files into multiple files, with the beginning of each split overlapping each other (for example: file 1 will be row 1-4000, then row 2 will be 3000-7000, and row 3 will be 6000-10000, etc.)

```
chunk_size = 4000
def write_chunk(part, lines):
    with open('data_part_'+ str(part) +'.csv', 'w') as f_out:
        f_out.write(header)
        f_out.writelines(lines)
        
with open("8-0new2.csv", "r") as f:
    count = 0
    header = f.readline()
    lines = []
    # for line in f:
    for line in range():

        count += 1
        lines.append(line)
        if count % chunk_size == 0:
            write_chunk(count // chunk_size, lines)
            lines = []
    # write remainder
    if len(lines) > 0:
        write_chunk((count // chunk_size) + 1, lines)
```

this is my current code to split the csv into 4 files, any idea to improve it so it can write the csv with overlapping rows?

Comment: You could split your files into pieces of `1,000` rows each. After then you can concat them back together. In your example you would use the 4th file (row 3001 to 4000) twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the data to test this thoroughly but should work:

```
CHUNK = 4_000
OVERLAP = 1_000

def write_csv(lines, filename, header):
    with open(filename, 'w') as csv:
        csv.write(header)
        csv.writelines(lines)

def get_csv_gen():
    part = 1
    while True:
        yield f'data_part_{part}.csv'
        part += 1

get_csv_name = get_csv_gen()

with open('8-0new2.csv') as csv:
    header = csv.readline()
    lines = csv.readlines()
    for offset in range(0, len(lines), CHUNK-OVERLAP):
        write_csv(lines[offset:offset+CHUNK], next(get_csv_name), header)
```